# bundle exec rake assets:precompile - database configuration does not specify adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

After 24 hours of trying to find the problem with my app. I finally found the problem.

I ran

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

and i kept on getting this error.

```
/Users/vezu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter

Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/vezu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bi...]
```

My database.yml file looks like this

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: ndoda_development
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ndoda_test
  pool: 5
```

Comment: m8 where is your production db configuration?))

Comment: You don't need it on Heroku. Heroku handles that for you. Sorry i forgot to mention that i use heroku.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The simple solution was to  add one simple line to my application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

And everything works.

Comment: Just a note: make sure you add the above line to your config/application.rb. I added it to the config/environments/production.rb by mistake which will NOT work

Comment: PSA in Rails 4.x this option has been removed

Answer (score 10):

This should work:
    rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development

It tries to load up your production environment, when your database.yml doesn't include it.

Comment: A note for anyone using Asset Sync. Setting the RAILS_ENV to development will prevent Asset Sync from syncing after compilation.

Answer (score 7):

Do this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: ndoda_development
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: ndoda_test
  pool: 5

# Add the below...

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  encoding: unicode
  database: ndoda_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:
```

Heroku will overwrite your database.yml with its own version, regardless of what you put in there. **However**, your rake task running in the Production environment requires a variable, so give it a dummy one.

As noted above, you can also add 'config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false' to your production.rb. If set, Heroku requires it be set to 'false'.

Comment: Its worth noting that starting with Rails 4 Heroku now no longer overwrites your database.yml

Answer (score 2):

This solution stopped working with rails 4, here is the updated one: just pass a dummy database as mentioned in this article:

https://iprog.com/posting/2013/07/errors-when-precompiling-assets-in-rails-4-0

The command is:
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname assets:precompile

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was this:

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Access your server via ssh and type that command in, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have some **dummy** `production` entry in your local `config/database.yml` file

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: your_local_database_name
```

I've come across the same error in 2016 with Rails 4.2.6 and Capistrano 3.4.
We were precompiling the assets during the deploy script just before uploading them together with the code, but rake assets:precompile needs some production entry, even if it's just a dummy one. Source: https://github.com/TalkingQuickly/capistrano-3-rails-template/issues/12

Answer (score -2):

call `rake assets:precompile:all`