# bootstrap-rails gem production error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, production-environment

Hi I have a basic devise signup form using twitter bootstrap that I am trying launch into production. It works fine in development. There is a problem with the bootstrap assets in production.

I have tried it without the group => assets, and the:git => ... part but it still does not work.

When I have

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

The site loads without the bootstrap styling. when it is set to false, I get an error = We're sorry, but something went wrong.

this is the gem I am using:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :group => :assets, :git => 'http://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git':
```

My production.log:

Processing by HomeController#index as HTML

```
    Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (21.8ms)
Compiled bootstrap_and_overrides.css  (916ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled home.css  (1ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled application.css  (1209ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled jquery.js  (5ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js  (0ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap.js  (211ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled home.js  (136ms)  (pid 31389)
Compiled application.js  (426ms)  (pid 31389)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5535ms (Views: 5520.6ms | ActiveRecord: 12.9ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for  at 2012-10-15 14:57:24 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (213.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 337ms (Views: 295.6ms | ActiveRecord: 11.8ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" fo at 2012-10-15 15:38:17 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (211.1ms)
Compiled bootstrap_and_overrides.css  (871ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled home.css  (1ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled application.css  (1199ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled jquery.js  (5ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js  (0ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js  (0ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js  (0ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js  (0ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js  (0ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js  (0ms)  (pid 415)
Compiled twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js  (0ms)  (pid 415)
"production.log" 755L, 39196C
```

I'm running a linode ubunto 10.04 lts server, nginx, unicorn and deploying with capistrano

I've been trying to solve this issue for a couple of days. Your help is much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you precompiling assets? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: Huge thanks! that was part of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mccannf mentioned in the comments I was not precompilling the public assets.

When I ran: bundle exec rake assets:precompile

I got an error:

/Users/vezu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /Users/vezu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter

then I followed this Stackoverflow post: [bundle exec rake assets:precompile - database configuration does not specify adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879587/bundle-exec-rake-assetsprecompile-database-configuration-does-not-specify-ada)

and added the below line in config/application.rb

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

then when I deployed to production it worked.