# Tried several fixes: Heroku/Rails 4 Assets Precompile Error

Tags: heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

Looks like this is a common issue, so let me begin by saying I've done a lot of research already.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432825/heroku-precompile-assets-failed-on-rail-4-app) thread, I ran

`heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp`

Then I made sure that assets precompile locally by running

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

They do.

I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879587/bundle-exec-rake-assetsprecompile-database-configuration-does-not-specify-ada) tip, setting

`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

in my config/production.rb and config/application.rb.

Also, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354539/heroku-does-not-compile-files-under-assets-piplines-in-rails-4) issue, I've made sure I have the heroku gems installed:

```
gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
```

Then I made sure I had `bin` in my path by following [this heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline).

Then I made sure I followed the "Getting Started with Rails 4.x.x" [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4) on heroku.

I've also followed another answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354539/heroku-does-not-compile-files-under-assets-piplines-in-rails-4) and placed the following in `application.rb` and `production.rb`

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Here's the error I get when running `git push heroku master`:

```
   Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

It seems like `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` should've worked, because it seems like it's trying to load the production database during precompliation.

I've made all these changes and they've been pushed to master in `git`. Now what should I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, sorry about this. I guess I hadn't pushed the effects of `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. Hopefully this serves as a number of resources for this issue.

#### Edit

In order to do this, I ran `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. Then I committed this with

```
git add -A
git commit -m "precompiled assets"
git push origin master
git push heroku master
```

Comment: There is no `initialize_on_precompile` in Rails 4 either

Comment: Could you explain how did you fix "I guess I hadn't pushed the effects of RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile."?Preferably for a rails noob :)

Comment: @HalilÖzgür there are two answers. When you type `RAILS_ENV=production` you are telling rails to start using the production settings, same as on heroku, so if there is an error, you will be able to see it before you push. The other part to this is that when you compile assets locally, you get a `public/assets/manifest` file generated. If heroku sees this, they won't run `rake assets:precompile` that's why he is adding them to his git repo, so heroku sees the manifest file.