# Rails 3.2 asset compilation issues on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, precompile

It seems a lot of people are having similar problems.  I consulted this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015724/tried-several-fixes-heroku-rails-4-assets-precompile-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821864/config-assets-compile-true-in-rails-production-why-not), and [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150209024319/http://blog.55minutes.com:80/2012/04/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-4-troubleshooting/#styles-not-loading), among others. I have found a lot of topics concerning these issues, but the posted solutions have been unable to find a definitive fix.  I am currently running rails 3.2.8 with ruby 1.9.2, and Heroku stack cedar.

### I am having two major, related issues:

#### 1)  My projects are pushing some assets - not all - to heroku.###

Per suggestions in other threads, when I place:

```
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

in my /config/application.rb,

```
    config.serve_static_assets = true
    config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
```

in /config/environments/production.rb, and

```
    gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

in my gemfile, the push will precompile successfully, however **the application.js file is empty on Heroku:**

[image: js issue1]

#### 2)  Precompiling before a push successfully puts JS on Heroku, but it is no longer recognized.###

After removing

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
```

from /config/production.rb, and running

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

committing and pushing results with index.html.erb **not recognizing JS despite application.js present & non-empty** as shown below:

[image: js issue2]

[image: js issue3]

I feel as if I have tried all combinations of these solutions to no avail.  I have not yet updated the applications to Rails 4, is this a good idea to do at this time?

Any other suggestions where to go from here?

#### Oddly, in another Rails 3.2 app of mine, I get a similar error only the first time I visit###

Once the page loads, simply hitting refresh loads all content and the errors go away.  This app has none of the attempted solutions above in its codebase.

[image: other]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, what solved it for me was specifying my ruby version in the gemfile.

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

No answer, but this may help. I precompile using the options below, which means only MD5 versions are created, this helped me fix a few issues.

```
rake -v --trace assets:precompile:primary RAILS_ENV=production
```

I also always do this before a precompile:

```
rake assets:clean
```

Also, double-check the exact MD5'd name, both in the html and the name of the file in heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. When I updated the Rails version from 3.2.8 to 3.2.11 it Worked!

Comment: Since that post I haven't had the error again.  I think it was a combination of the above steps, including an upgrade to rails 4.  Also adding "config.serve_static_assets = true" in production.rb seemed to help.  Thanks!