# database configuration does not specify adapter when preparing asset precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

I recently switched my test database to be postgrsql from sqlite3.  Since doing so, when I follow the instruction here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline on deploying my assets to heroku, I get the following error:

```
database configuration does not specify adapter
```

This happens after running this step

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I tried following the instructions from this post and it did not work.

[bundle exec rake assets:precompile - database configuration does not specify adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879587/bundle-exec-rake-assetsprecompile-database-configuration-does-not-specify-ada)

I'm guessing it has something to do with my database.yml file, which is here

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: playerpong_database
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  I added a production section to my database.yml file.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: playerpong_database
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: unicode
  host: my_app_url
```

I didn't think this was needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a dummy database as mentioned in this article:

https://iprog.com/posting/2013/07/errors-when-precompiling-assets-in-rails-4-0

The command is: bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname assets:precompile

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are running

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

where as your file has development adapter , and so the error comes to be like the adapter is missing.
You need to either change the environment article to development

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

or change the development directive to production

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: playerpong_database
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
```